# turn file into dictionary with values for character repetition count

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I am trying to write a function that will take in a text file that is saved in my computer, then it will read through all the names in the file and get only the first character for each name, which are each in a new line. These characters will be the keys for the dictionary I am creating and the values will be how many times a name in the file starts with that letter. So if the text file is the following:

```
Mary
Jane
Anna
Judith
Kim
Melody
Myriam
Lauren
Betty
Holley
```

then my dictionary should be:

```
{'A':1, 'B':1, 'H':1, 'J':2, 'K':1, 'L':1, 'M':3}
```

so far my code looks like this:

```
def newDictionary():
names={}
char = []
file = open(names)
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    1char = file.read(line[1])
    1char.append(char)
    for keys,values in names():

return names
```

I know its not finished but I don't know how to add the number of times the first character repeats and then make these my values corresponding to the right key. Please help me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
with open('a.txt') as f:
    counter = Counter([line[0] for line in f])
print(counter)
```

This will print:

```
Counter({'M': 3, 'J': 2, 'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'H': 1, 'K': 1, 'L': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

The smart way to do this is with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a special type of dictionary for counting things. But you can also do it with a normal dictionary:

```
def newDictionary(filename):
    names = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            first = line[0]
            if first in names:
                names[first] += 1
            else:
                names[first] = 1
    return names

names = newDictionary('qdata')
print(names)
```

**output**

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'H': 1, 'K': 1, 'J': 2, 'M': 3, 'L': 1}
```

---

There are a couple of problems with the code in your question.

Variable names must begin with a letter or underscore, they can't start with a number, so `1char` gives a Syntax Error.

You're using `names` as the name of a dictionary, but you're also trying to give it as the file name to `open()`, that's not going to work. Even if you set `names` to the proper file name earlier in your code, once you do `names={}` it now refers to an empty dictionary.

You get the lines of the file into a list with `lines = file.readlines()` but then you do `file.read(line[1])`. You don't need to read again from the file: you've already got all of its contents. And besides, after `file.readlines()` the file pointer's at the end of the file, so you *can't* read any more data from it (unless you "rewind" the file using its `.seek()` method).

Also, you want the first char of `line`. You can get that with `line[0]`, since Python uses zero-based indexing; `line[1]` gets you the 2nd character in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes will make your code workable:

```
def newDictionary():
    names={}
    lines = open(in_file).readlines()
    for item in lines:
        names[item[0]]=names.get(item[0],0)+1
    return names
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'H': 1, 'K': 1, 'J': 2, 'M': 3, 'L': 1}
```